# Massonary grids AJAX loading issues

Tags: jquery, layout, masonry

I am using [masonry](https://github.com/desandro/masonry) scripts on my wordpress theme for post massonary layout http://prntscr.com/l14jh7.
When I click load more button, it's overlapping on the grids http://prntscr.com/l14kbl

My js codes

```
$("#load-more-posts").on('click', function (e) {
    var nexturl = $(this).attr('href');

    $.get(nexturl, {}, function (data) {
        var posts = $(data).find(".lorepostsgrids").html();
        //console.log(posts);
        $(".lorepostsgrids").append(posts);

        var postgrids = $('.lorepostsgrids');
        imagesLoaded($postgrids,function(){
            $postgrids.masonry('appended',items);
            $postgrids.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.grid-item'
            });

        });


        var newpagelink = $(data).find("#load-more-posts").attr("href");
        if(newpagelink){
            $("#load-more-posts").attr('href', newpagelink);
        }
        else{
            $("#load-more-posts").hide('slow');
        }
    });
    return false;
});

var newpagelink = $("#load-more-posts").attr("href");
if(!newpagelink){
    $("#load-more-posts").hide('slow');
}
```

Solution please

Comment: You probably need to re-init masonry after you insert the Ajax content into the DOM.

Comment: I fixed it myself.

Comment: How did you fix it? @Hans